# web service is not working on server side

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, asmx

i have created a we bservice named `test.asmx` which looks like this:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://insforia.com/Webservices/StockTickers/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[WebMethod(Description = "Using stock symbol gets delayed stock information from Yahoo.", EnableSession = false)]
public string[] GetQuote()
{
    string username = Session["username"].ToString();
    string company = "BSE-100.BO+COALINDIA.BO+TCS.BO+WIPRO.BO+SBIN.NS+MNM.BO+RCOM.BO+TATASTL.BO+GMRINFRA.BO+ICICIBANK.BO";
    string stockcodes = "sl1c6";

    string url = "http://in.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" + company + "&f=" + stockcodes;

    var webRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
    var webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        buffer = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }

    var buffer = buffer.Replace("\"", "");
    buffer = buffer.Replace("\r\n", ",");
    var bufferList = buffer.Split(new char[] { ',' });

    return bufferList;
}
```

and i am calling this web service in my aspx page like this:

```
private string userid = "admin";

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Session["username"] = userid;
     test oo = new test();
     bufferList = oo.GetQuote();
}
```

the thing is its working perfectly in my localhost but when i uploaded it on server its giving me an error that it couldn't find the `test`

to see the exact error this is the link :

```
http://insforia.com/Webservices/StockTickers/stockmain.aspx
```

i don't understand what to do? why this is happening. i know this is a very stupid question to ask here but i am trying this from yesterday.

Comment: what is your test class ?

Answer (score 0):

try to dont use session.
send param for userName;

```
public string[] GetQuote(string UserName)
{
...
    return bufferList;
}
```